# cassandra-driver installation with something other than pip

Tags: python, cassandra, installation, pip, easy-install

I am currently attempting to download the cassandra python driver (https://github.com/datastax/python-driver). Because of restrictions set by the project I am unable to use pip to install anything. Is there another way that I could download this particular driver such as easy-install or something? I can't find anything on the github page or datastax that references anything except for pip.

Comment: What about [manual installation](http://datastax.github.io/python-driver/installation.html#manual-installation) section?

Comment: @Selcuk I changed the proxy setting to get pip working properly, but now I am getting a connection error when trying to install futures. I am using 'pip install futures' and getting a response that says the connection is broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known'))'" /simple/futures/'

Comment: You can download the whl file from pypi and install using pip locally